# retrieving tag value causes infinite loop

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

in the below posted xml file i am trying to display the value of the tag element belongs to the

```
<node id="125801" lat="53.0705997" lon="8.7818627">
```

I wrote the below code but it goes in infinite loop

why that is happening and how to solve it?

**xml file**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="osmconvert 0.7T" timestamp="2014-11-27T21:22:02Z">
<bounds minlat="53.01034" minlon="8.480959" maxlat="53.61063" maxlon="8.991268"/>
<node id="125799" lat="53.0749415" lon="8.7868047"/>
<node id="125800" lat="53.071932" lon="8.7840591"/>
<node id="125801" lat="53.0705997" lon="8.7818627"> // <====this one
    <tag k="highway" v="motorway_junction"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Bremen-Neustadt"/>
</node>
<node id="20973856" lat="53.0979621" lon="8.8667934"/>
<node id="20973857" lat="53.0976313" lon="8.868052"/>
<node id="20973858" lat="53.0974051" lon="8.86891"/>
<node id="20973859" lat="53.0972418" lon="8.8694694"/>
<node id="20973860" lat="53.0933247" lon="8.8705933"/>
<node id="20973861" lat="53.0935016" lon="8.8706564"/>
<node id="20973894" lat="53.1002332" lon="8.8842715"/>
<node id="20973895" lat="53.099723" lon="8.8858872">
    <tag k="highway" v="traffic_signals"/>
</node>
</osm>
```

**code**:

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <= 2; i++) {
        String expr0 = "//node[@lat='53.0705997'][@lon='8.7818627']/following-sibling::tag["+i+"]/@v";
        xPath.compile(expr0);
        String s = (String) xPath.evaluate(expr0, document, XPathConstants.STRING);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see no way the loop can go invinite in the code snippet posted. Apart from that, your XPath doesn't correctly correspond to the XML, i.e `tag` **is not** `following-sibling` of the `node` element, it is `child` of the `node` element instead :

```
String expr0 = "//node[@lat='53.0705997'][@lon='8.7818627']/child::tag["+i+"]/@v";
```

or simply, as most people will do :

```
String expr0 = "//node[@lat='53.0705997'][@lon='8.7818627']/tag["+i+"]/@v";
```

Comment: thank it works now..but what if i want to display the tag value for the the 2nd node.? in other words,  for [@lat='53.071932'][@lon='8.7840591'] how can i display the corresponding tag values?

Comment: @user2121 That shouldn't be different. What's the problem?

Comment: i mean, given the same above posted xml file...                                                       String expr0 = "//node[@lat='53.071932'][@lon='8.7840591']/tag["+i+"]/@v";...does not give any result....why

Comment: @user2121 that `node` doesn't have child `tag` : `<node id="125800" lat="53.071932" lon="8.7840591"/>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want your tag, this suffices:

```
String expression="//node[@id=125801]";
```

and for the chidren:

```
String expression="//node[@id=125801]/*";
```

For iterate:

```
String expression="//node[@id=125801]";


NodeList nodes  = (NodeList)  xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

for(int i=0; i<nodes.getLength(); i++)
{
 Node the_node = nodes.item(i);

 if(the_node instanceof Element)
    {
    Element element=(Element) the_node;
    // get what you want
```

hope it helps